# Nuget: Unable to retrieve results from one or more sources

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, nuget

I am getting the following error when browsing Nuget packages in VS2019 after changing my Windows 10 password:

> "Unable to retrieve results from one or more sources"

What I have tried so far:

1. Signed out and back into Visual Studio
2. Pressed the "Clear All Nuget Cache" button
3. Sign-out and back into the Devops web admin

Comment: There should be more log messages telling your which source couldn't be queried. Start there. Although you tagged `azure-devops`, it's better not to waste time on azure-devops credentials if it's not the source with the issue. If you can't find the information in Visual Studio, run `dotnet restore -v:n` from the command line if all projects in your solution are SDK style, otherwise download nuget.exe from nuget.org and run `nuget restore`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What solved the problem was to update the password in the Windows Credential Manager for the corresponding source domain.

Answer (score 0):

Its being late but may be it helps someone.
Just type `%temp%` in run command and delete all cache you will be all good to go